# laravel postgres having method error with alias column

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I made a search page with filters. In Laravel the code is:

```
$select = [
   'car.id as id',
   'car.car_name as name'
];

$q = Car::where('car.active',1);

    if ($price) {   
        $select = array_merge([
DB::raw("(select p.car_price * $variable from prices p where p.car_id = car.id) as unique_price"
)],$select);
        }

$q->select($select);

$q->having('unique_price', '>=', 2000);
```

I am using postgresql as laravel database and i get the error **unique_price** does not exist.

then i write:

```
dd($q->get());
```

and the "unique_price" column exists.

What is the problem? how can i fix it? in mysql works.

Comment: Did you mean `p.car_price as unique_price`. Though your code seems odd to me.

Comment: i edit it. please check

Comment: you can try leftJoin

Comment: what do you mean? can you give me an example?

Comment: you should debug and show the actual SQL command